# Cereal could not find any Output serialization functions

Tags: c++, cereal

I do not know why I am getting this error when trying to compile.  I have tried adding almost all of the types.  I am trying to serialize a set of RegDoneEntry's .  I know the call to serialize is not here but I can't get beyond just this. The below is updated to reflect recommendations.

The error I get now is

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol 
>   "public: static class std::set,class std::allocator > RegDoneList::mylist" 
>   (?mylist@RegDoneList@@2V?$set@VRegDoneEntry@@U?$less@VRegDoneEntry@@@std@@V?$allocator@VRegDoneEntry@@@3@@std@@A)   CerealTest  CerealTest.obj  1

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cereal/archives/binary.hpp"
#include "cereal/types/set.hpp"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

RegDoneList myRegDoneList;

int main()
{
    myRegDoneList = RegDoneList();

    myRegDoneList.mylist = std::set<RegDoneEntry>();
    std::ofstream ss("c:\\reg.bin", std::ofstream::binary | 
        std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);

    cereal::BinaryOutputArchive oarchive(ss);
    oarchive(myRegDoneList); // Write the data to the archive

}

bool operator<(const RegDoneEntry& lhs, const RegDoneEntry& rhs)
{
    return lhs.rawData < rhs.rawData;
}
```

And the Header file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cereal/archives/binary.hpp"
#include "cereal/types/memory.hpp"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <stdio.h>


class RegDoneEntry
{
public:
    std::string rawData;
    int operation;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & archive)
    {
        // serialize things by passing them to the archive
        archive(rawData, operation);
    }
    friend bool operator< (const RegDoneEntry &left, const RegDoneEntry &right);

};


class RegDoneList
{
public:
    static std::set<RegDoneEntry> mylist;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & archive)
    {
        // serialize things by passing them to the archive
        archive(mylist);
    }
};
```

Comment: What's error do you get? Also, whats use of `    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & archive)` member?

Comment: The error is "Cereal could not find any Output serialization functions".  the template is what cereal requires.

Comment: I had the same error. Turns out serialize was defined in my class as a private method, not a public. Followed a tutorial: https://rubentorresbonet.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/an-overview-of-data-serialization-techniques-in-c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class `RegDoneEntry` should have `serialize` method defined too.

```
struct RegDoneEntry
{
  std::string rawData;
  int operation;

  template<class Archive>
  void serialize (Archive& ) {  //... 
  } 
};
```

Next, you want to create set of RegDoneEntry objects, but your code will not be compiled without `operator<` for RegDoneEntry class.
You should add also this operator in definition of RegDoneEntry

```
struct RegDoneEntry {
   // ...code from above
   bool operator < (const RegDoneEntry& ) const {
       // your comparison
   }
};
```

And the last thing, you have set as static member, but you didn't define it in source code, so you should add this line too

```
std::set<RegDoneEntry> RegDoneList::mylist;
```

Comment: This is of great help but I have one error left.  I will update the code above

Comment: @Jeff `mylist` in `RegDoneList` is still as static member, you should add `std::set<RegDoneEntry> RegDoneList::mylist;` before `RegDoneList myRegDoneList;` in main.cpp file. Static variable of class must be defined in .cpp file of source code.